# Correct Way to Pass Dates from Angular to Web API 2

Tags: angularjs, date, asp.net-web-api2, iso8601

I have an Angular application that takes dates (date only not time) and posts them to a Web API 2 REST service.  We are running into an issue when someone from India uses the application due to timezone issues.

Currently the Angular app is converting the date into ISO8601 format in UTC timezone and sending them to Web API.  When the data is received on the Web API side, the date ends up being incorrect.  If 6/21/2016 was put into the form, the date ends up coming over as 6/20/2016.  The desired solution is to have the actual date value entered in the form be the date value received by the API.

One proposed solution is to treat the dates as strings instead of Dates and then just pass the date portion.  This just seems like a hack to me and doesn't seem like the "correct" way of doing it.

What is the correct way of handling this situation?

Given the fact that the application has a lot of date field inputs is there an easy way to implement the solution across all Date input values?

Comment: Use `momentjs` in any datetime picker controls (you did not mention if it was a field or a control). When extracting the date to be sent to the server extract it as ISO8601 formatted string. Send that to the server and use the DateTime object on the server side which should deserialize the date with the DateKind.Utc flag. For the reverse treat dates as strings in angular, webapi (when using json.net) will serialize datetimes to ISO notation.

Answer (score 0):

The date format `yyyy-MM-dd` will be accepted in US / India so you can pass it so to your WebAPI. In JavaScript before posting you can alter the date like this.

```
$scope.MyDate = $filter('date')($scope.MyDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', timezone);
```

If you want time too, the format will be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ`

Comment: The problem is that 4/19/2016 (IST time) gets converted to 2016-04-18T18:30:00Z (UTC time).  Then when Web API receives it, it appears to be ignoring the UTC timezone and parsing the date as 4/18/2016 (EST time).